# How to bind an array of objects for controller PUT action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project and I need to submit data in a specific format:

```json
{
    "readings": [
      {
          "type": "temp",
          "value": "37",
      },
      {
          "type": "wind",
          "value": "10",
      },
    ] 
}
```

I have a simple class `Reading`:

```cs
public class Reading
{
  public string Type {get; set;} = "";
  public int Value {get; set;} 
  
  public Reading() { }

  public Reading(string type, int value)
  {
      Type = type;
      Value = value;
  }
}
```

And I have a class `ReadingSet`:

```cs
public class ReadingSet {
  public List<Reading> Readings = new List<Readings>();
   
  public ReadingSet() { }

    public ReadingSet(List<Reading> readings)
    {
        
        foreach (var reading in readings)
        {
            Readings.Add(reading);
        }
    }

}
```

In my controller I have:

```cs
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult<Score>> ComputeScore(ReadingSet readings)
{
  // ...
}
```

The problem is that the readings.Readings.Count is zero, even though I am passing three readings in. I think that the `Type` and `Value` for each Reading are not binding property (or at all) but I don't know how to go about it. Can anyone point me in the right direction to understand how to make this happen?

Comment: Which serialisation framework are you using, `Newtonsoft`, `System.Text.Json`, etc. Could be the capitalisation of "Readings" vs "readings".

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to .NET, how would I find that out? :)

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: dotnet v7.0.304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because `Readings` is a field, not a property. Try changing:

```
public List<Reading> Readings = new List<Readings>();
```

to:

```
public List<Reading> Readings { get; set; } = new List<Readings>();
```

Comment: So it seems I need to both change it to a Property AND use FromBody (as @coyote suggested).

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in the API, try adding [FromBody]:

```js
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult<Score>> ComputeScore([FromBody] ReadingSet readings)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I think the model binder might check the body automatically?

Comment: can you check and see if it works for you?

Comment: Yup, I did but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: I just tested this out in combination with SBFrancies answer and it works if I do both these things, but no with only one.